# behavior of parent and child for a signal handler

Tags: unix

A process has a 'fork' call after a signal handler has been registered [for SIGINT]. what happens when SIGINT is sent through command line ? whether parent gets exited or child or both ? parent and child both are running infinite while loops.

Answer (score 17):

If you do `fork` (without further `exec*`) after a signal handler has been registered, the same signal handler will be used in parent and child processes. That is, if you do something other than `exit` in your `SIGINT` handler, neither parent nor child will exit (how `SIGINT` was sent is irrelevant here).

If you mean a `SIGINT` sent from the *terminal* (by `vintr` character which is usually `Ctrl+C`): it will be received by processes using the *terminal* as controlling terminal. That is, unless you detach child or parent from controlling terminal, both will react to `Ctrl+C` by calling your `SIGINT` handler.

Comment: But the signal handler is registered before fork(), so the child shouldn't have the copy. After fork() the child should execute the statements following the fork(). signal handler registration will only be in the parent.

Comment: @Puneet It *is* inherited by the child, whatever you think of how it *should* be. See `man sigaction`. What's so strange about it? File descriptors opened before `fork` are inherited too. The only thing special about signals is that non-default, non-ignore *handlers* are reset on `execve` & friends (because the handler's address makes no sense in a new executable), but nothing like this happens on `fork`.